# How to ensure disposal of an IDisposable returned anonymously into a consuming method?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, using, idisposable, polly

I'm creating an instance of `HttpRequestMessage` and return it to be used through the HTTP client.

```
HttpClient Client { get; init }
HttpRequestMessage GenerateRequest() { ... }
```

Then, I'm using Polly to execute the call under a policy with a couple of iterations and exponential delay in between.

```
using HttpResponseMessage response = await RetryPolicy
  .ExecuteAsync(() => Client.SendAsync(GenerateReqest()));
```

Since `HttpRequestMessage` implements `IDisposable`, I've been recommended to ensure invocation of `Dispose()` as the object goes out of scope, like this:

```
using HttpResponseMessage response = await RetryPolicy
  .ExecuteAsync(() => 
  {
    using HttpRequestMessage request = GenerateRequest();
    Client.SendAsync(request);
  });
```

Is there a simpler syntax to achieve that? I could call the disposer explicitly but that doesn't change the fact that I still would have to wrap it in a body instead of going simple lambda expression, which I'd prefer.

I went through the `HttpRequestMessage` class and it's `Dispose()` as well as the underlying `HttpContext` and so on. As far I can see, there's no actual registration in an event or such that requires the disposability, so I guess it's there in case something extra unusual happens. So I'm considering skipping the `using var name = ...` syntax and let the GC deal with it eventually.

One way or the other, I'd like to have only lambda expression and if it's possible, I can apply disposer too, though, under the condition that it won't require me to create a multi-statement.

Answer (score 2):

Depending what your `GenerateRequest` does, you most probably don't need to call the `Dispose` explicitly. There is a [github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/886) which details when to call the `Dispose` on the `HttpRequestMessage` and `HttpResponseMessage`. Let me quote here the relevant part:

> It's not important in these scenarios. Disposing a request or response only calls `Dispose` on their `Content` field. Of the various `HttpContent` implementations, only `StreamContent` needs to dispose anything. `HttpClient`'s default `SendAsync` fully buffers the response content and disposes the stream, so there's nothing the caller needs to do.

So, if your `GenerateRequest` does not use `StreamContent` then don't bother to `Dispose` it by yourself.